# jq: extract value based on different (calculated) value

Tags: json, bash, date, select, jq

I am trying to filter down a very large json file (AWS output from `aws rds describe-db-snapshots`) into just a list of snapshots for deletion.

The final list of snapshots should be older than 60 days. I can discern their age via their `SnapshotCreateTime`, but I need their `DBSnapshotIdentifier` value to be able to delete them.

Greatly stripped down for SO purposes, below is the input.json file.

```
{
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "SnapshotCreateTime": "2017-08-22T16:35:42.302Z",
  "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1b",
  "DBSnapshotIdentifier": "alex2-20170822-0108-bkup",
  "AllocatedStorage": 5
}
{
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "SnapshotCreateTime": "2017-06-02T16:35:42.302Z",
  "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
  "DBSnapshotIdentifier": "alex-dbs-16opfr84gq4h9-snapshot-rtsmdbinstance-fr84gq4h9",
  "AllocatedStorage": 5
}
{
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "SnapshotCreateTime": "2017-04-22T16:35:42.302Z",
  "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
  "DBSnapshotIdentifier": "alex3-20170422-update",
  "AllocatedStorage": 5
}
```

I know about `select` but from what I can tell it can't handle the math needed for the time comparison in a one-liner. I figured I'd need to branch out to bash, so I've been messing with the following (clunky) workaround. It's not working, but I figured I'd include it as proof of effort.

```
THEN=$(date +'%Y%m%d' -d "`date`-60days")

while IFS= read -r i
    do
        awsDate=$(jq -r '.SnapshotCreateTime' < $i) // get time
        snapDate=$(date -d $awsDate +'%Y%m%d') //convert to correct format

        if [ $snapDate -gt $THEN ] //compare times
        then
            // something to copy the ID

        fi

    done < input.json
```

In this case I'd be looking for an output of

```
alex-dbs-16opfr84gq4h9-snapshot-rtsmdbinstance-fr84gq4h9
alex3-20170422-update
```

Comment: Minor JSON issue: you should not have a trailing comma after the `5` in each of the `"AllocatedStorage": 5,` key/value pairs.

Comment: @jq170727 thanks for catching that, it was an error in simplifying that isn't in the real data. Edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an all-jq solution (i.e. one that does not depend on calling the `date` command). You might like to try a variation, e.g. passing some form of the date in, using one of the command-line options such as `--arg`.

jq currently does not quite understand the SnapshotCreateTime format; that's where the call to `sub` comes in:

```
def ago(days): now - (days*24*3600);

select(.SnapshotCreateTime | sub("\\.[0-9]*";"") < (ago(60) | todate))
| .DBSnapshotIdentifier
```

After fixing the sample input so that it is valid JSON, the output would be:

```
"alex-dbs-16opfr84gq4h9-snapshot-rtsmdbinstance-fr84gq4h9"
"alex3-20170422-update"
```

To strip the quotation marks, use the -r command-line option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which defines a filter function which uses **select**, **sub**, **fromdate** and **now**.

```
def too_old:
    select(   .SnapshotCreateTime
            | sub("[.][0-9]+Z";"Z")   # remove fractional seconds
            | fromdate                # convert to unix time
            | now - .                 # convert to age in seconds
            | . >  (86400 * 60)       # true if older than 60 days in seconds
    )
;

  too_old
| .DBSnapshotIdentifier
```

If you place this in a file `filter.jq` and run jq with the `-r` option e.g

```
jq -M -r -f filter.jq input.json
```

it will produce the output you requested:

```
alex-dbs-16opfr84gq4h9-snapshot-rtsmdbinstance-fr84gq4h9
alex3-20170422-update
```